# iOS UIPageViewController child view under Bottom Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uipageviewcontroller, uiedgeinsets

I had an UIPageViewController embedded in a NavigationController embedded an TabBarController.
I supposed every child view of the UIPageViewController fits the size within the UITabBarViewController.

The first child view looks fine:

[image]

Switch to the next (vertically), it's view suddenly resizes and the view length expands over the bottom bar:

[image]

Actually it's not under the bottom bar but clipped to that size (which means if you pull up the view you still cannot see the whole but the cut text).

I did unchecked every related view controller's Under Bottom Bar & Adjust Scroll View Inset but nothing works.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in table view controller viewDidLoad() method.

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO;
```

OR 
you can set property in Interface Builder:
Uncheck Extend Edges: Under Bottom Bars, Under Opaque Bars.